# CUDA out of memory - Memory Management in Pytorch

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, conv-neural-network, gpu

I'm working with a computer that has more than one GPU. Each GPU has 16 GB of Memory.

I made the program through Jupyter Notebook. However, I cannot access the 2 GPU's. As soon as the program consumes all the memory on GPU:0 it cannot move to GPU:1.

The error that appears is:

> File /opt/npad/shared/conda/gpu/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2450, in batch_norm(input, running_mean, running_var, weight, bias, training, momentum, eps)
> 2447 if training:
> 2448     _verify_batch_size(input.size())
> 2450 return torch.batch_norm(
> 2451     input, weight, bias, running_mean, running_var, training, momentum, eps, torch.backends.cudnn.enabled
> 2452 )
>
> CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 9.57 GiB (GPU 0; 15.78 GiB total capacity; 9.73 GiB already allocated; 4.91 GiB free; 9.75 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrfw1.png).

I saw a way to use the command that the error asks to work around, and it appeared like this:

> os.environ["PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"] = "max_split_size_mb:512"

How would I go about overcoming this error?

I saw a way to use the command that the error asks to work around, and it appeared like this:

os.environ["PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"] = "max_split_size_mb:512"

How would I go about overcoming this error?

Comment: Please, check [this pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html)